# How to get tty to recognise shift-F2 (and other key combinations)?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, tty

Firstly, apologies if my question or terminology doesn't make sense - I'm still wrapping my head around terminal, console, shell etc.

I can use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> shortcut in an application in a terminal running on the desktop, but I can't use it in a tty terminal. Some other shortcuts don't work either, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>. Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>F1</kbd> to print its character value, I can see that they differ - in a desktop terminal with `TERM=xterm-256color`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> returns `^[[1;2Q` whereas in tty1 with `TERM=linux` it returns `^[[26~`. Setting tty to appear as xterm with `export TERM=xterm-256color` makes the <kbd>F</kbd> keys return letters (without even pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> first), and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> simply prints `~`.

Is there any way to have the tty virtual terminals recognise all the same shortcuts and key combinations that the X terminal does?

Answer (score 2):

First, you should not set `TERM=xterm-256color` in the Linux console, most apps will fail to work properly. Stick with `TERM=linux`.

Second, let's clarify that altering the value of `TERM` does *not* change the escape sequences generated by the keypress. The graphical emulator, or the Linux kernel in case you're using the console, cannot see if you alter the environment variable in the process running "inside" the terminal emulator; in fact, there might be multiple processes running in that terminal (their standard input connected there) with different `TERM` variables. Changing `TERM` might change though how an application reacts on those keypresses.

> Is there any way to have the tty virtual terminals recognise all the same shortcuts and key combinations that the X terminal does?

Terminal emulators don't *recognize* these sequences you're talking about. They *emit* them, and the terminal-based applications (text editors, file managers etc.) *recognize* them.

Run `infocmp` (or `infocmp [terminal-name]` such as e.g. `infocmp linux`) to list the capabilities/features of a terminal, including the sequences generated by function keys. Look for `kf2` for <kbd>F2</kbd>, and `kf14` for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. Generally <kbd>Shift</kbd> should result in an offset of 12.

As far as I recall from a couple of years ago, some of the keymaps on the Linux console have an offset of 10 instead, and this discrepancy potentially causes all sorts of misbehavior in various apps.

You didn't mention how (e.g. in what app) you're trying to catch these keypresses. If you're configuring an existing piece of software which requires concrete sequences, you'll probably have to teach it (at least) two different values, one for `xterm` and friends, and one for `linux`.

If you are developing your own app and don't want to have escape sequences hardcoded or specified in a config file, you should probably rely on `libtinfo` to read the terminfo capabilities, or use a higher level screen drawing and keyboard handling library such as `ncurses` or `slang`.